# WPF C# access combo box on another class running on another thread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

Parameters can't be passed when starting a new thread, so what is the best way to access UI element values in another class which is running on another thread?

Best Regards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parameters can be passed when starting a new thread. See the [ParameterizedThreadStart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.parameterizedthreadstart.aspx) delegate.

Don't access UI elements on another thread, you'll end up in a world of hurt. Instead you should access the View Model (ie. the data) that the item is bound to.

Comment: @OJ Not sure what you mean by ViewModel, I'm going to Google it.

Comment: It's an object that you bind to your View which contains the data you want to interact with.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use the Dispatcher of the control you're trying to access. But of course, OJ's suggestion of using the ViewModel is better. You *are* using a ViewModel, right?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Invoke to read values out of your forms.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b.aspx